# How to parse </sub> and </sup> in bibliography

Tags: bibliographies, subscripts, superscripts

I use Mendeley to generate the `.bib` file and this results in articles with  `<sub>` and `<sup>` tags in the title.

```
@article{Testtest2016,
author = {Testtest},
title = {{Why O{\textless}sub{\textgreater}2{\textless}/sub{\textgreater} and O{\textless}sup{\textgreater}2-{\textless}/sup{\textgreater}?}},
year = {2016}
}
```

Currently they are compiled in the bibliography as `[2] Testtest. Why O<sub>2</sub> and O<sup>2-</sup>? 2016.` whereas I'd like O<sub>2</sub> and O<sup>2-</sup>

Can I make LaTeX replace the tags with `$_{...}$` and `$^{...}$` ? If not I'll find another way (e.g. editing `bib.bib` on-the-fly) but I'd prefer LaTeX doing it automatically. I do not want to change the title inside Mendeley as the titles are coming from the DOI search.

I'm sorry if this has already been adressed but I can't find any answer.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit. (By the way, we usually don't put a greeting or a "thank you" in our posts. While this might seem strange at first, it is not a sign of lack of politeness, but rather part of our trying to keep everything very concise. Upvoting is the preferred way here to say "thank you" to users who helped you.)

Comment: Just to clarify: do you have `<sub>...</sub>` *and* `<sup>...<\sup>` tags, or only `<sub>` ones?

Comment: Welcome, i don't think it is the right way to make LaTeX understand HTML/XML, but instead make Mendeley produce a correct bib file. Or likely, to provide Mendeley with a decent input. Most automatic bib generators provide some faulty stuff.

Comment: I changed the OP to make it clearer

Comment: @Johannes_B If it's not possible I will edit the file on-the-fly but that would have been easier

Comment: Please add at least the `.bib` entry that produces those tags

Comment: The entry produced by Mendeley is ***completely*** wrong. If it produced the *tags*, something could be done, but instead it produces code for printing the tags as text.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should edit the entries and tell the maintainers of Mendeley to stop outputting such rubbish.

Here's a workaround that assumes you don't need `\textless` anywhere else and that the tags are just `<sup>...</sup>` and `<sub>...</sub>`, without nesting.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{Testtest2016,
author = {Testtest},
title = {{Why O{\textless}sub{\textgreater}2{\textless}/sub{\textgreater} and O{\textless}sup{\textgreater}2-{\textless}/sup{\textgreater}?}},
year = {2016}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{article}

\makeatletter
% get rid of the closing braces
\def\textless{\afterassignment\textless@\let\next= }
% get the tag type
\def\textless@#1#{\@nameuse{textless@#1}}
% code for <sub>
\def\textless@sub#1#2/sub#3{%
  \ensuremath{_{\let\textless\relax#2}}%
  \egroup % matches the first brace
}
% code for <sub>
\def\textless@sup#1#2/sup#3{%
  \ensuremath{^{\let\textless\relax#2}}%
  \egroup % matches the first brace
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\cite{Testtest2016}

\bibliographystyle{plain}
\bibliography{\jobname}

\end{document}
```

[image]